# F# - How to show RProvider results in FSI?

Tags: r, f#, deedle

I am working on samples scripts on how to use RProvider:
http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html

However, I never get in FSI the result as they get in the example page. I would just get:

```
val it : SymbolicExpression =
   RDotNet.SymbolicExpression {Engine = RDotNet.REngine;
                          IsClosed = false;
                          IsInvalid = false;
                          IsProtected = true;
                          Type = NumericVector;}
```

When in the sample code, they get, for R.colMeans(...)

```
val it : SymbolicExpression =
 Ozone  Solar.R  Wind  Temp  Month   Day 
 NaN      NaN  9.96 77.88   6.99  15.8
```

I am pretty sure that the data frame (Deedle) that I pass to R using R.as_data_frame(...) is not empty. In a way it seems that the code isn't executed.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Have you loaded the RProvider like so: `#load "RProvider.fsx"`? If not, try doing that or adding the following line at the top of your file: `do fsi.AddPrinter(fun (synexpr:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) -> synexpr.Print())`